# Customize leaflet routing error (options)

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am using Leaflet-routing-machine,

I added the error control to my map like this :

`L.Routing.errorControl(this.control).addTo(map);`

for style I used this :

```
.leaflet-routing-error {
  width: 320px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 153, 164);
  padding-top: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

this is what I got :

[image]

Ididn't find a lot of explanations about. Have anyone know how to customise this more, change language, hide/show... ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [source code](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/blob/master/src/error-control.js) 
you can redefine the **header** and the **fromat message** function

```
L.Routing.errorControl(control, {
            header: 'Routing error',
            formatMessage(error) {
                if (error.status < 0) {
                    return 'Calculating the route caused an error. Technical description follows:  <code><pre>' +
                        error.message + '</pre></code';
                } else {
                    return 'The route could not be calculated. ' +
                        error.message;
                }
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

I believe that in your control you can redefine this two options

also you may be able to use the leaflet element with classes **leaflet-bar leaflet-routing-error** and inject more html code on it as they do to create the alert

`var L = require('leaflet');`

```
        onAdd: function() {
            var header,
                message;

            this._element = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-routing-error');
            this._element.style.visibility = 'hidden';

            header = L.DomUtil.create('h3', null, this._element);
            message = L.DomUtil.create('span', null, this._element);

            header.innerHTML = this.options.header;

            return this._element;
        }
```

so retrieving the `div` of class or id `leaflet-routing-error` and injecting on it your desired html component template should be fine